# The type or namespace name 'ListPicker' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls'?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, namespaces, .net-assembly

So I've been tinkering with some code, which I kinda regret, originally the problem was the Microsoft.Phone.Controls was in the wrong path directory which I've removed and re-added to the references successfully.

I'm getting a new error, and it seems just to be the listpicker element which it doesn't like.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this in an update on your previous question, but I'll move it here. :)

The `ListPicker` is a control in the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone, which is an add in set of controls published by Microsoft.

When you add a control to the page, you need to add a reference to the .dll to the XAML page and map it to a prefix that will tell Visual Studio where to find the control:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
                            xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
```

Note the `toolkit` prefix.

Now you can add a control like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker></toolkit:ListPicker>
```

If those items are set up correctly, you might also need to check if the .dll was "blocked" when you downloaded it. Browse to the .dll in Explorer, then right click and look at the bottom for a button called Unblock. If it's there, click it.

The references in the XAML can be tricky to set up. There's a sample app available for the toolkit that can be helpful.

Comment: No problem. It's a different question, so it doesn't hurt to break it out.

Comment: Thing is it's been working before, just now after editing it's decided to be awkward.  See here in xaml view, I have the list picker tool kit already there? http://postimage.org/image/rxzinvhx9/

Comment: The blue squigglies mean that Visual Studio can't find the .dll. I think the issue is that your namespace definition of the `xmlns:toolkit` prefix (located in the `page` tag) is pointing to the wrong place because you removed and readded the reference.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right about it not pointing to the correct place, but how can I go about re-pointing it? Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: Sweet. Glad to help. :) Those pesky references are one of the not-fun parts of working with WP7 and XAML. If you happen to have Resharper, it can create them for you automatically.